# Eccentric Angle of hyperbola

Tags: conic-sections

Lets say, a vertical hyperbola whose transverse axis is $y$ axis. Its parametric coordinates $(a\tan \theta, b\sec \theta)$. This  $\theta$ represents the eccentric angle related with auxiliary circle. If any point of the hyperbola is located in the 1st quadrant (according to the proof), I understand the identity of $\theta$. But I can't find this angle in other quadrants. So, does this angle really have a geometric significance?

NB- I am a 11th grader. And don’t have much idea on Hyperbolic Trigonometry

Comment: https://www.geogebra.org/m/TyHchwuK

Comment: I watched it before. The question was about a vertical hyperbola

Comment: Angle $\theta$ must be measured with respect to $y$-axis.

Comment: The difference between "vertical" and "horizontal" is just a rotation by $\frac\pi 2$.